# SQL Server : comma-separated List based on offset values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The SQL query looks like this:

```
Declare @Values nvarchar(max) , @From int , @To int
Set @Values = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j'
Set @From = 3 , @To = 7
```

The values must be split into rows based on `@From` and `@To`. Based on the above query, required output is

```
 c d e f g
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval SQL.NET](http://eval-sql.net/)

If you have a C# background, you may might consider this library which let you use C# syntax directly in T-SQL

```
DECLARE @Values NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @From INT ,
    @To INT

SELECT  @Values = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j' ,
        @From = 3 ,
        @To = 7

-- The index start at 0 and not at 1 in C#
DECLARE @sqlnet SQLNET = SQLNET::New('
values.Split('','').Skip(from - 1).Take(to - from + 1)')
.ValueString('values', @Values)
.Val('from', @From)
.Val('to', @to)

-- In multiple rows
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[SQLNET_EvalTVF_1](@sqlnet)

-- In same rows
SELECT  SQLNET::New('
var splits = values.Split('','').Skip(from - 1).Take(to - from + 1).ToList();
return string.Join('' '',  splits);')
.ValueString('values', @Values)
.Val('from', @From)
.Val('to', @to)
.Eval()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a string splitter for this. Here is [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden.

```
DECLARE @Values NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @From   INT,
        @To     INT

SELECT  @Values = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j',
        @From   = 3, 
        @To     = 7

SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + Item
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@Values, ',')
    WHERE ItemNumber BETWEEN @From AND @To
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: This  is working .  And also how can I get the  count of the values in the comma seperated list.

Comment: `SELECT DATALENGTH(@Values)/2 - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@Values, ',', ''))/2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
declare @Values nvarchar(max) 
      , @From int 
      , @To int

set @Values = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j'
set @From = 3
set @To = 7

;with cte as(
select substring(@Values, charindex(',', @Values, 1) + 1, 4000) as st
     , substring(@Values, 1, charindex(',', @Values, 1) - 1) ch
     , 1 as rn
union all
select substring(st, t + 1, 4000) as st
     , substring(st, 1, t - 1) ch
     , rn + 1 as rn
  from cte
    cross apply (select case when charindex(',', st, 1) = 0 then 8000 else charindex(',', st, 1) end) t(t)
  where rn < @To
    and datalength(st) > 0)

select stuff((
select ' ' + ch as 'text()'
  from cte
  where rn between @From and @To
  order by rn
  for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
  option (maxrecursion 0)
```